# Ticket price calculator code not working

Tags: python

i can not figure out how why this code will not count to 20. i need to create a code that will count 20 tickets but if 10 or more tickets are purchased a 10% discount is given. here is my code so far

```
start = 1
end = 21
increment = 1
TicketPrice = float(input("Enter the price of one ticket: "))

while TicketPrice <= 0:
    print("The price of one ticket must be greater than zero.   Try again!")
    TicketPrice = float(input("Enter the price of one ticket: "))

def main():

    print('Tickets\t      Total Price')

    for Tickets in range (start, end, increment):
        Total = TicketPrice * Tickets
        while Tickets >= 10:
            Total = 0.90 * Tickets * TicketPrice


        print(Tickets, '\t     ', Total)

main()
```

edit: i changed the while loop to if and that solved the problem but i now need to limit the code to 2 decimal points without rounding up or down

Comment: your while loop once it's hit will never return, what you want is an `if` block

Comment: @photoionized, if that's the answer, please post it as an answer. (but please also specify which while loop you mean)

Comment: thank you that helped but now i need to figure out how to limit the decimal points to 2

Answer (score 0):

```
for Tickets in range (start, end, increment):
    Total = TicketPrice * Tickets
    if Tickets >= 10:
        Total *= 0.90
```

As you originally wrote it, the iteration where Tickets is 10 while hit this while loop and recompute the 10% discount forever.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_ticket_price():
    price = float(input('Enter the price of one ticket: '))
    if price <= 0:
        print('The price of one ticket must be greater than zero. Try again!')
        return get_ticket_price()
    return price

ticket_price = get_ticket_price()

total = 0
for ticket_count in range (1, 21):
    price = ticket_price
    if ticket_count >= 10:
        price = ticket_price - (ticket_price * .1)
    total = total + price

print(total)
```

Comment: Every answer you give has basically zero explanation, how is anyone going to learn if you never explain anything?

Comment: If you put the effort of writing that comment into writing some explanation, you would serve a better purpose.